# cv.Save and cv.Load (array)

Tags: arrays, opencv, load, save

I need to save and load an array, but I get this error:

```
   cv.Save('i.xml',i)
 TypeError: Cannot identify type of 'structPtr'
```

This is the code:

```
import cv
i = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
cv.Save('i.xml',i)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because *cv.Save* needs to receive the object to be stored in the file as an OpenCV object. For example, the following is a minimal workable example that saves a numpy array in a file using *cv.Save*:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

i = np.eye(3)
cv2.cv.Save('i.xml', cv2.cv.fromarray(i))
```

As you can see [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31207/how-do-i-load-an-opencv-generated-yaml-file-in-python/), arrays should be converted back to numpy from OpenCV as well after reading.

Regards.

Comment: please avoid answering outdated topics. the old opencv cv api should no more be used, and is removed in latest 3.0

Comment: It is an old, but unanswered question. I looked, but found no solution about it. How do you solve the problem with the new API then?

Comment: you can't because that api is no more around.

Comment: Will cv2.cv not be available anymore either? I changed the solution to use the new api. Perhaps that's what you are talking about. Regards.

Comment: it's the same thing, and it's gone. only cv2 is left. and there, you would use numpy functionality to load and store Mat's